# change slider value dynamically

Tags: javascript, slider, bootstrap-slider

I am using bootstrap slider and creating slider controls dynamically in a group of three (Easy,Medium,Hard). I want to change the max value of the remaining two sliders dynamically. Total values of all three sliders in a group should not exceed 100. I can't seem to think of anything as all the sliders have same class. Any idea how to achieve this.?

**Here is a jsfiddle link** : https://jsfiddle.net/sqj1djyv/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
Container 1
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
Easy: 
<input class="slider" name="easy[]"data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="1"/>
</div>
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
Medium: 
<input class="slider" name="medium[]"data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="1"/>
</div>
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
Hard: 
<input class="slider" name="hard[]"data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="1"/>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
Container 2
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
Easy: 
<input class="slider" name="easy[]"data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="1"/>
</div>
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
Medium:
<input class="slider" name="medium[]"data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="1"/>
</div>
<div class="container" style="padding:20px">
Hard: 
<input class="slider" name="hard[]"data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="1"/>
</div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("input.slider").slider({
    tooltip:'always'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:nth-child()` to target the correct slider.  Something like

```
$('container:nth-child(2)').attr('name', dynamicNameValue);
```

You'd probably want to add an additional class to the container values though so you could target each slider separately.  `containerTop` something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this won't solve the problem

Comment: @johnny046 I see, I misunderstood that you were trying to update the slider name attribute.  What attributes are you trying to update?   `data-slider-max`?  Is there any reason this same method couldn't be used for that attribute instead of name?

Comment: The problem is actually I can't identify each slider individually.

Comment: And how is this not fulfilling your needs? You should be able to use nth-child() to target a specific slider based off what number you put in there. You could even use .children() to target all children.  Please be more specific on what this isn't achieving for you so can I help better. Thanks!